# Generate JSON files for Hightcharts with PHP from a TCP string

Tags: php, json, graph, highcharts, tcp

I need to generate 2 JSON files with PHP from 2 TCP commands in order to build a Highchart graph.

The first JSON file will contain the graph informations :
Graph Title, Graph Subtitle, Y axis title and a number related to the type of graph to be displayed.

The TCP string (from an IoT distant board) sends to the server the following arguments :

- Name of JSON info file to built
- Graph Title
- Graph Subtitle
- Graph Y axis title
- Type of graph to be displayed

**http:myserver/graphs/make-json_info.php?jsonfilename=S_007_nfo.json&graphtitle=S_007_Sensor&graphsubtitle=Office-Temp&Yaxistitle=Temp-Sensor&GraphType=3**

How could i make a JSON file with a PHP file named 'make-json_info.php' from this TCP string ?

JSON file should look like this :

```
 {
   chart: {
     type: '/*...*/'
  },
  xAxis: {/*...*/},
  yAxis: {/*...*/},
 plotOptions: {/*...*/}
  /*...etc...*/
}
```

Regarding the 2sd JSON file needed to generate the graph, the IoT board sends every minutes another TCP string that contains :

- Name of JSON data file to fill-in
- Datetime stamp
- Sensor value

**http:myserver/graphs/make-json_data.php?S_007_data.json&datatime=1488271800000&value=22.5**

Expected JSON file should be like this :
http://s529471052.onlinehome.fr/graphs/S_007_data.json

Can you show me how to write my two PHP files, these should generate 2 JSON files in order to built the expected Highcharts Graph afterwards ?

So far, i tried to extract informations from the JSON data file and JSON info file fro graph information is missing.

```
see jsfiddle below
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fbmohjgy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm uncertain about many things in you question, but I will try my best.

The JSON file that contain the graph information... Does it only contain meta infromation about the graph (title, type, etc), or does the file also contains xAxis Data and yAxis Data...

From these two lines in your question, it seems like it may also contains the actual data:

```
xAxis: {/*...*/},
yAxis: {/*...*/},
```

Apologies if I got it all wrong, but this is what I came up with.
It is not tested, but should give you an idea of what to do:

Let's start with the second file/script first.

```
<?php
$file_name = $_GET['jsonfilename'];
$datatime = $_GET['datatime'];
$value = $_GET['value'];

$file_content = file_get_contents($file_name); //read data from json file
$temp_file_data = json_decode($file_content, true); //convert json string into php array
$temp_file_data['date'][] = [$datatime, $value]; //add your new values to the array
$new_file_content = json_encode($temp_file_data); //encode your new array as a json string

file_put_contents($file_name, $new_file_content); //save the new json string back to the file
?>
```

Now for the first PHP script. This script will use the json file from the above code to create the complete json file that the graph will use:

```
<?php
$file_name = $_GET['jsonfilename'];
$graphtitle = $_GET['graphtitle'];
$graphsubtitle= $_GET['graphsubtitle'];
$Yaxistitle= $_GET['Yaxistitle'];
$GraphType = $_GET['GraphType'];

$data_json = file_get_contents($file_name); //read data from json file
$data_array = json_decode($file_content, true); //convert json string into php array

$xAxis = [];  //create array that will contain all xAxis values
$yAxis = [];  //create array that will contain all yAxis values

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data_array['data']); $i++)
{
    $xAxis[] = $data_array['data'][$i][0]; //add xAxis data from first json file to the xAxis array
    $yAxis[] = $data_array['data'][$i][1]; //add yAxis data from first json file to the yAxis array
}

$json_array = [];  //declare the array that will be converted to the final JSON string that the graph will use
$json_array['chart'] = ['type' => $GraphType];
$json_array['xAxis'] = $xAxis;
$json_array['yAxis'] = $yAxis;
$json_array['plotOptions'] = ['graphtitle' => $graphtitle,
                              'graphsubtitle' => $graphsubtitle,
                              'Yaxistitle' => $Yaxistitle];
?>
```